# mySQLi filtering database results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Okay i'm going to attempt to reword the question that was put on hold. I have a table in my database called `anime` this is what it looks like:

[image]

the code below mainly focuses on the tags row in the database which will has tags listed like this: tag1, tag2, tag3 etc..

I am trying to make a search that works via selecting keywords (tags) from a dropdown options menu (well 3 dropdown menus) since all the keywords (tags) are fixed and the tags within the database are fixed (the same) i can use

```
$tag_x = "tag1";
$tag_y = "";
$tag_z = "";

$tag_search = "%(?=.*$tag_x)(?=.*$tag_y)(?=.*$tag_z)%";

 // Connect to Database
require 'connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT id, title, category FROM anime";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
        $tags = $row["category"];
        if (preg_match($tag_search, $tags)) { 
            echo $row["id"];
        }       
        }
    }
  else
    {
    echo "0 results";
    }
$conn->close();
```

this code can show matches for 1 - 3 keywords (tags)

the problem is i don't think this is a great way to do it and also i need to run it three times to get a list of results that have 3 matches first then 2 matches then 1 tag match, in a list.

////// OLD QUESTION BELOW THAT WAS PUT ON HOLD. (not sure if i should delete.) ///////////

Hello I am new to mysqli and databases in general I have been trying to find a way to filter down SELECT queries and display the results.

I have a database with lists of items that all have related tags and I am trying to show the row(s) and their information when a user makes a search query (via drop down menus). The data looks like this:

```
ID  NAME        TAGS                CAT IMG_FILE_NAME
1   demo one    tag1, tag2, tag3    ... something.png
2   demo two    tag2, tag4          ... something.png
3   demo three  tag0                ... something.png
4   demo four   tag3, tag4, tag5    ... something.png
5   demo five   ...                 ... something.png
6   ...         ...                 ... ...
```

the search will work like this

```
<label for="x">I am looking for:</label>
<select id="x">
  <option value="t1">Tag 1</option>
  <option value="t2">Tag 2</option>
  <option value="t3">Tag 3</option>
</select>

<label for="y">That has:</label>
<select id="y">
  <option value="t4">Tag 4</option>
  <option value="t5">Tag 5</option>
  <option value="t6">Tag 6</option>
</select>

<label for="z">and is:</label>
<select id="z">
  <option value="t7">Tag 7</option>
  <option value="t8">Tag 8</option>
  <option value="t9">Tag 9</option>
</select>
```

and the user may select `x = tag 2` `y = tag 5` `z = tag 8`

and then hit search or go and it would pull/show the results from the database with the tags the selected and failing that show the ones with the next closest matching tags (2 tags then 1 tag etc..)

can the WHERE statement do this?

I think 90% of my problem with finding an answer to this question is how i'm wording the question in the first place but after 3+ hours looking for something that works and not finding anything this seems like the best place to ask once again! any help would be amazing! and code/links to code would be greatly apperated!

Comment: post your SQL in your question

Comment: *"can the `WHERE` statement do this?"* - Yes, read up on SELECT https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html and String Comparison Functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: *"and the user may select x = tag 2 y = tag 5 z = tag 8"* - so, is that `AND` or `OR` or `AND/OR`? Your question is unclear and have voted to closed based on your entire question, including no code to work with.

Comment: in your case a `LIKE` could do the job, but that's not a good database-design. You should have your tags in a seperate table (or maybe 3 in your case) and then "filter" them via join-select statements. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: I'm not sure how to be more clear, in a single column called "tags" i want to list tags (separated by commas) like: "tag1, tag3, tag9" and to be able to grab all rows that meet the "tag search" (have the tags)

Comment: Good improvement to the question by the OP, voted to re-open. You weren't able to be clearer because you lacked the terminology and concepts, which the answer gave you. This is how we all learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma-separated values in your `TAGS` column are sub-optimal.  You can, possibly, make this work like so

```
SELECT NAME, CAT, IMG_FILE_NAME
  FROM item
 WHERE TAGS LIKE CONCAT('%', ?tag1, '%')
   AND TAGS LIKE CONCAT('%', ?tag2, '%')
   AND TAGS LIKE CONCAT('%', ?tag3, '%')
```

where `?tag1` etc are the values provided by your user. But this sort of wildcard matching (`WHERE TAGS LIKE '%tag3%'`, for example) is both error-prone and horribly slow if your table is large. (If your user gives you less than three tags, you need to use less than three `WHERE` clauses.

Do you want this to work well? Put the tags in their own `tag` table, with columns like so:

```
item_id
tag
```

So, if you item with id = 2 has tag2 and tag4, you'll have two rows in the `tag` table

```
 2  tag2
 2  tag4
```

Then, you can search with queries like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) MATCHES, i.NAME, i.CAT, i.IMG_FILE_NAME
  FROM tag t
  JOIN item i ON t.item_id = i.id
 WHERE t.tag = ?tag1
    OR t.tag = ?tag2
    OR t.tag = ?tag3
 GROUP BY i.NAME, i.CAT, i.IMG_FILE_NAME
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, i.NAME
```

This will give you a list of the items that match any or all the tags your user specified, with the ones that match more tags listed first.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you should write something like:

```
SELECT field_a, field_b FROM table WHERE field_x='2' AND field_y='5' AND field_z='8'
```

it is obvious that you have to adapt it to your table and to your field names but can give you a hint.
Based on your comment you should do something like:

```
SELECT field_a, field_b FROM table WHERE tags='2, 5, 8'
```

but note that this will look for the exact string. So if you have a row where `tag = '5,2,8'` (same tags but different order) you will not get the result.
It is better (IMHO) to use three columns like tag_1, tag_2 and tag_3 and store each value in a single column? So that my first example will become

```
SELECT field_a, field_b FROM table WHERE tag_1='2' AND tag_2='5' AND tag_3='8'
```

Comment: *si signore*. However, OP's question is unclear and have posted a few comments under their question. Especially comment *numero tre*.

Comment: I agree with you "amico mio". I have just shown an example and added that it was just an hint. I also think that OP should be much more clear about the question

Comment: Sorry if I have misunderstood, but if I have a column called "tags" and each row has more than one tag (separated by commas) like: "tag1, tag3, tag9" the above wouldn't work, would it? What are "fields" referring to?

Comment: see my updated answer. Anyway as also @Fred -ii- is saying unless you show us the table structure any answer we give you is just a guess.

Comment: @user1871802 "field" *a.k.a.* "row/column".